# fs.readFile inside async.waterfall doesn't return data

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

After much research and tests, I am stucked into my waterfall :

```
async.waterfall([
  //first 5 functions are going fine and passing expected vars to the next function the function below is the pb
  // eg adSetId var comes just fine from previous function
  function(imgName,adsetId,callback) {
    fs.readFile('./shopifyImages/'+imgName  , 'base64' ,function(err,imgData) {
      callback(null,imgData,adsetId);
    });
  }
]);
```

`imgData` is always returning empty value.
There is no error from the function and its working fine ouside of the waterfall (`fs.readFile` works as expected), some `console.log` gives empty `imgData` as well.

FULL CODE

```
async.waterfall([
    //GET AD ACCOUNT FOR USER
    function(callback) {
        var sqlAd_act = vsprintf('select * from fbTokens where userId=%s', [roomIDCook.userId]);
        connection.query(sqlAd_act).then(function(rows) {
            //console.log('rows '+rows);
            callback(null, rows[0].ad_act);
        });
    },
    //SET CAMPAIGN
    function(ad_act, callback) {
        fb.api('/act_' + ad_act + '/campaigns', 'post', {
            'status': 'PAUSED',
            'name': 'GENIE 2'
        }, function(data) {
            //console.log('data: ' + util.inspect(data))
            callback(null, data.id, ad_act);
        });
    },
    //SET ADSET
    function(campaignId, ad_act, callback) {
        console.log('ad account ' + ad_act);
        console.log('campaignId ' + campaignId);
        fb.api('/act_' + ad_act + '/adsets', 'post', {
            'daily_budget': 500,
            'start_time': '2017-02-18T20:11:25+0000',
            'end_time': '2017-03-25T20:11:25+0000',
            'name': 'new adset',
            'optimization_goal': 'LINK_CLICKS',
            'objective': 'LINK_CLICKS',
            'campaign_id': campaignId,
            'status': 'PAUSED',
            'billing_event': 'LINK_CLICKS',
            'bid_amount': 2,
            'targeting': {
                "geo_locations": {
                    "countries": ["US"]
                },
                "publisher_platforms": ["facebook"]
            }
        },
        function(res) {
            if (!res || res.error) {
                console.log(!res ? 'error occurred' : util.inspect(res.error));
                return;
            }
            //console.log(util.inspect(res));
            callback(null, res.id)
        });
    },
    // CREATE THE AD FOR THE ADSET
    function(adsetId, callback) {
        // set img
        var imgUri = 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1336/5343/products/9_b75df43c-1660-4aeb-89b7-418df1a9853c_1024x1024.jpg?v=1466985077';
        var DOWNLOAD_DIR = 'shopifyImages/';
        var imgName = 'TEST2.jpg';
        console.log('adsetId ' + adsetId);
        // download img
        request.head(imgUri, function(err, res, body) {
            console.log('content-type:', res.headers['content-type']);
            console.log('content-length:', res.headers['content-length']);
            request(imgUri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(DOWNLOAD_DIR + imgName));
            console.log('adsetId ' + adsetId);
            callback(null, imgName, adsetId);
        });
        // read img for facebook
    },
    function(imgName, adsetId, callback) {
        fs.readFile('./shopifyImages/' + imgName, 'base64', function(err, imgData) {
            console.log(util.inspect(err));
            console.log(util.inspect(imgData));
            callback(null, imgData, adsetId);
        });
    },
    function(imgData, adsetId, callback) {
        console.log(imgData);
        console.log('adsetId ' + adsetId);
    }
], function(error, c) {
    console.log(c);
});
```

Comment: Could you show the callbacks from the function before? Are you sure you are passing a valid `imgName`?

Comment: I think you'll have to show more of the execution context here including how `imgName` is set and what could possibly be different in this function versus the others.   There's not enough info shown here.

Comment: Hi there thanks fr answer, yes pretty sure that the imgName is fine, also tried with filename "hardcoded" instead of var name. Also tried with a bad filename, then the function thrown an error as expected.

Comment: You also don't check the error, could you `console.log` it and show us the result?

Comment: If it works fine outside and not inside, you're probably providing it incorrect arguments.

Comment: sorry i did not post the error, but i already console.log(util.inspect(err)); and it returns nothing :)

Comment: regarding the args i already console.log the vars imgName and adserId and the values are here :(

Comment: Then there is no reason for it to not work. I'd `console.log` and `util.inspect` the hell out of that function and the one above to make sure every variables are set to the value I expect it to have

Comment: console.log(util.inspect(err));
       console.log(util.inspect(imgData));
       console.log(imgName);
       console.log(adsetId);
GIVES


null -> err
'' -> imgData
TEST2.jpg -> imgName
6052105978048 -> adsetId

Comment: DrakanSAN thanks a lot, but i already did :)

Comment: You can ping someone with @username so that they are notified you posted a new comment.
Are you sure request.pipe doesn't have a callback or event indicating the file have been downloaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because streams are asynchronous, you have a timing issue.  You are doing this:

```
request(imgUri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(DOWNLOAD_DIR + imgName));
callback(null, imgName, adsetId);
```

But, you are not waiting for the streams to complete before calling the `callback()` and going on to the next step where you expect the `imgName` file to already exist.  So, you are trying to read the newly created file before it has finished being written.

You need to register an event handler for that stream so you know when that stream has finished writing and then and only then should you call the `callback(null, imgName, adsetId)` to go onto the next step.

I'm not a streams whiz so there might be a more elegant way to do this, but here's one solution:

```
// CREATE THE AD FOR THE ADSET
function(adsetId, callback) {
    // set img
    var imgUri = 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1336/5343/products/9_b75df43c-1660-4aeb-89b7-418df1a9853c_1024x1024.jpg?v=1466985077';
    var DOWNLOAD_DIR = 'shopifyImages/';
    var imgName = 'TEST2.jpg';
    console.log('adsetId ' + adsetId);
    // download img
    request.head(imgUri, function(err, res, body) {
        console.log('content-type:', res.headers['content-type']);
        console.log('content-length:', res.headers['content-length']);
        console.log('adsetId ' + adsetId);
        var outputStream = fs.createWriteStream(DOWNLOAD_DIR + imgName);
        outputStream.on('finish', function() {
            callback(null, imgName, adsetId);
        });
        outputStream.on('error', function(err) {
            callback(err);
        });
        request(imgUri).pipe(outputStream);
    });
```

FYI, it's conceptually odd to write data to a file in one step and then in the next step read it back into memory.  Quite inefficient.  Why not just read it the first time into memory or if you still want it in a file, then write it to a file, but retain in memory the data you wrote?

Comment: @direxit: You can mark the answer as correct by clicking on the green mark next to it. You also receive rep for that.

Comment: @jfriend00 You're the boss ! *****, was that stream unfinished thing, and yes i can avoid one step :)